# Manually scheduling a queued job on Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, backgroundworker, sidekiq, job-scheduling

I have a lot of jobs in queue, and thats fine.

Sometimes I'd want to do very specific jobs first, or stop processing the queued jobs for a while. For that I was thinking to grab all jobs in the queue (plus or minus those that are working now) and to schedule them for 1 hour from now

I couldn't find a way to do this in the api. Is this possible?

something like

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new.each{ |job| job.schedule(1.hour.from_now)}
```

Comment: You can shedule jobs via https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq

Comment: thats for recurring jobs, I can't use it to move jobs from the queue to the scheduleset

Comment: You already looked at the queuing ideas [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues) ?  I understand this would set up permanent rules vs your scenario of when times are busy but this seems easier to manage.